# Adding quotes to an appveyor.yml echo line

Tags: bash, yaml, appveyor

I have this line that adds some version info to my build:

```
install:
  - 'echo "export const VERSION = Git Hash: %APPVEYOR_REPO_COMMIT%" > version.js'
```

obviously that is no valid JS because the quotes are missing. Could someone help me so I can get this string written to my `version.js` file:

```
export const VERSION = 'Git Hash: some_hash'
```

I did try some variations of escaped and unescaped quotes but build times are somewhat agonizing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are wasting the use of single quotes by quoting that sequence element. You can not have a plain scalar (because of the mid-sentence colon+space), but it often much better to use literal block style scalars. The following is equivalent to your YAML:

```
install:
  - |-
    echo "export const VERSION = Git Hash: %APPVEYOR_REPO_COMMIT%" > version.js
```

And so you can use single quotes for the echo parameter and still have double quotes within those:

```
install:
  - |-
    echo 'export const VERSION = "Git Hash: %APPVEYOR_REPO_COMMIT%"' > version.js
```

(the `-` after `|` is needed to strip the final newline)

Alternatively, assuming Appveyor uses a relatively standard echo, you might be able to use its `-e` option:

> ```
>     -e     enable interpretation of backslash escapes
> ```

in which case you don't need to use literal block style scalars to get something less readable:

```
install:
  - 'echo -e "export const VERSION = \"Git Hash: %APPVEYOR_REPO_COMMIT%"" > version.js'
```

---

Please note that, according to the official YAML FAQ, whenever possible, the correct extension for a YAML file, is **`.yaml`**. You can tell Appveyor not to default to the `.yml` extension, using the `Custom configuration .yml [sic!] file name`. For my YAML parser I have also set this to be a hidden file: `.appveyor.yaml`

Comment: `-e` isn't required; `\"` is a literal quote in a double-quoted string, not a special escape sequence like `\n` to be interpreted. Ironically, `-e` is *not* part of standard `echo`; it's a `bash` extension to enable behavior that standard `echo` already implements.

Comment: it seems complicated: the literal block produces this error:  _While parsing a block collection, did not find expected '-' indicator._, the `e` option writes `-e   "export const VERSION = \"Git Hash:   7345f4609c0319da0592f4d6ffb04147ef4df92e\""` into version.js.

Comment: @three sorry, after looking at that code again (which against my normal practise I had not programmatically produced) I noticed that the last line was not indented enough. The `e` of `echo` should at least be under the `|`

Comment: The portable replacement for `echo -e` is called `printf`.

Comment: @Anthonthere we go, that did the trick. Could you update the answer so everybody who finds this will get it right too?